# How can I send SMS from one number to another number in android programatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android application. It requires to send text message (i.e.SMS) for OTP(One Time Password) purpose to user so he/she can enter the valid OTP code and get logged in to application. 
I was looking at SMSManager API provided by android framework which uses to send text messages from application itself. But I need to send a text message from my registered number to user.

How can we achieve this requirement?

Comment: you have to use sms gateway...

Comment: It's not very common do achieve that on a phone. Usually you would make use of a web service or an own server that sends the texts via your network

Comment: use bulk sms api, as suggested by @Toppers, and it will be paid api.

Comment: A service such as Clickatell.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send sms via your application this is the way.

`SmsManager.getDefault()` - get default instance of SmsManager

```
sendTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

Use this to send the SMS

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
```

don't forget 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

check this [link](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/06/send-sms-in-android-example.html#.VE9MwdKmh4k) for more info if required

Comment: This is for sending via your mobile device else u neeed an SMSC and send a rest request to it to forward the SMS.

Comment: please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad prior posting "answers" like this

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski added an explanation as well as an optional link thanks for the update will take care